# Why do i get a cartesian product instead of join?

Tags: php, mysql

The following code should return me the average numbers the first five players did in a game.

```
SELECT "Starting 5" as Flag, 
       count(gs.ID) as Games, 
       avg(s.min) as Min, 
       avg(s.P2M) as P2M, 
       avg(s.P2A) as P2A, 
       100*avg(s.P2M/s.P2A) as P2P,  
       avg(s.P3M) as P3M,  
       avg(s.P3A) as P3A,  
       100*avg(s.P3M/s.P3A) as P3P,  
       avg(s.FTM) as FTM,  
       avg(s.FTA) as FTA,  
       100*avg(s.FTM/s.FTA) as FTP,  
       avg(s.OFFENSE) as OFFENSE,  
       avg(s.DEF) as DEF,  
       avg(s.TOT) as TOT,  
       avg(s.AST) as AST,  
       avg(s.TO) as 'TO',  
       avg(s.ST) as ST,  
       avg(s.FV) as FV,  
       avg(s.CM) as CM,  
       avg(s.PTS) as PTS,  
       avg(s.P2M - s.P2A + s.P3M - s.P3A + s.FTM - s.FTA + s.TOT + s.AST + s.ST + s.FV + s.PTS - s.TO - s.CM) as EFF  
FROM gamesstats AS gs 
    INNER JOIN gamesstatsplayers as gp ON gs.id=gp.GameStatID 
    INNER JOIN players as p ON gp.PlayerID = p.ID 
    INNER JOIN stats as s ON gp.stat=s.id 
                         WHERE gs.HomeTeamID ='664' 
                         and gs.HomeScore > gs.VisitorScore 
                         and gp.IsHomePlayer = 1 
                         AND gp.IsFirst5 = 1 
                         AND gs.SeasonStart = '2010' 
                         AND gs.LeagueID = '145'
```

I should get 4 games and the averages in each. What I get is the avg of each player in a game. That means I get 20 games and 1/5 of the average I want in each. The problem is for some reason it makes a cartesian product instead of join. Was tryign to find the bug for several hours but can't seem to find it.

The table explanations:

gamesstats is for holding each game.

gamesstatsplayers is has a connection to a game via GameStatID and is responsible for each player stats in each game.

players is a table of all players there are.

stats is a table with just the stats, gamesstats has a link to stats to give you the stats of a whole team in a game(2 links, one for home and one for visitor), gamesstatsplayers has a link to stats to give you the stats of 1 player in 1 game. (That means stats is for two things).

Comment: Could you add some schema information?

Comment: It's easier to help if you include DDL and sample data (as INSERT statments). Most of us have time to answer questions. Most of us don't have time to reverse-engineer your query to derive what *might* be your schema, and then generate sample data on our own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without knowing the schema, this is a guess, but you probably need to group on the GameStatID, if that is the primary key for the game.

Comment: No, you didn't correctly understand what I want. I do not want 4 rows with an average for each, I want 1 row with the averages of those 4 already.

Comment: @Vadiklk: You say in your description, that you want ***"I should get 4 games and the averages in each"***. So, try this advice, adding `GROUP BY gs.id` at the end of your query.

Comment: I meant that the "Games" should return 4 and the averages should be average in a game. In one row.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use WHERE clause:

```
SELECT "Starting 5" as Flag, 
       count(gs.ID) as Games, 
       avg(s.min) as Min, 
       avg(s.P2M) as P2M, 
       avg(s.P2A) as P2A, 
       100*avg(s.P2M/s.P2A) as P2P,  
       avg(s.P3M) as P3M,  
       avg(s.P3A) as P3A,  
       100*avg(s.P3M/s.P3A) as P3P,  
       avg(s.FTM) as FTM,  
       avg(s.FTA) as FTA,  
       100*avg(s.FTM/s.FTA) as FTP,  
       avg(s.OFFENSE) as OFFENSE,  
       avg(s.DEF) as DEF,  
       avg(s.TOT) as TOT,  
       avg(s.AST) as AST,  
       avg(s.TO) as 'TO',  
       avg(s.ST) as ST,  
       avg(s.FV) as FV,  
       avg(s.CM) as CM,  
       avg(s.PTS) as PTS,  
       avg(s.P2M - s.P2A + s.P3M - s.P3A + s.FTM - s.FTA + s.TOT + s.AST + s.ST + s.FV + s.PTS - s.TO - s.CM) as EFF  
FROM gamesstats AS gs 
    INNER JOIN gamesstatsplayers as gp ON gs.id=gp.GameStatID 
    INNER JOIN players as p ON gp.PlayerID = p.ID 
    INNER JOIN stats as s ON gp.stat=s.id 
    WHERE
     gs.HomeTeamID ='664' 
     and gs.HomeScore > gs.VisitorScore 
     and gp.IsHomePlayer = 1 
     AND gp.IsFirst5 = 1 
     AND gs.SeasonStart = '2010' 
     AND gs.LeagueID = '145'
```

Comment: I used it, when writing it here I mistakenly deleted it. Nevertheless that was not the bug.